# XAgent - Domino Single Sign On

Tags: ajax, rest, xpages, lotus-domino

we are using "single sign on" on our servers in our company.
When opening an xpage application in the browser, the server logon mask is presented to the user.

Now we have the request to implement an REST service for a other non-domino application. We use the xagent pattern to implement this service.
How can the client authenticate itself against this service in a simple ajax call?

Thanks
Mario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mario,
you have options:

1. The internet site configuration in the Domino directory allows to specify exception URLs where a basic HTTP(s) authentication gets accepted. The calling client only needs to provide username/password according to the HTTP standard. If your calling client is Java, then the [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/) is a good choice since it handles all of that for you.
2. You could generate a LTPA token if the other system has access to the shared secret (e.g a WebSphere server or a F1 load balancer) and provide that as a cookie. Again the Apache HTTP client is a good choice to do that
3. You use the [SecureDomino](http://www.timetoact.de/ttacms.nsf/id/secdomen) plug-in (commercial) that can authenticate clients based on an IP address
4. You use [Tivoli Access Manager](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/create-a-transparent-ltpa-junction-with-tivoli-access-manager-6.1) (TAM) as proxy and generate the LTPA from Kerberos or NTML. [Puakma Webbooster SSO](http://www.puakma.net/puakma/website.pma/BoosterESSO) is a business partner alternative to TAM
5. You drag the project a little until 8.5.4 is out and use OAuth
6. You allow anonymous access but require credentials inside the XML Post (like the MetaWebLog API implementation in Domino Blogsphere)

**"If there isn't at least a handful of solutions for any given problem, it isn't IBM"™**